# Initialize multiple objects with different name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How can I  `Initialize` and `allocate` multiple objects with different name and pass it to the `NSArray`. from Below code the object is initialized once in loop and I need to initialized multiple times as per the For loop will go with different name..and then pass it to `NSArray`.please check the code below..
when **For** loop will start means **i=0** ..initialized item would be`tempItemi`
now next time when **i=1 and i=2** the `tempItemi` name will be same .how can i change this with in loop..and pass it to `NSArray *items`

```
for (int i = 0; i< [Array count]; i++)
{
    id object = [Array objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;


        ECGraphItem *tempItemi = [[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str = [objDict objectForKey:@"title"];

        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];
        tempItemi.isPercentage=YES;
        tempItemi.yValue=f;
        tempItemi.width=30;

        NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tempItemi,nil];
        //in array need to pass all the initialized values


        [graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean on each loop you want to have object tempItemi, tempItemi1, tempItemi2,...?

Comment: I. Have. No. Idea. What. You. Mean.

Comment: @Mike I was wondering that too, I dont think there is a way to actually modify the pointer/instance NAME without typing it

Comment: @Christien Wait so do you want to modify the actual NAME of the instance, why do you need that? That shouldn't make a difference in any scenario...

Comment: actually when loop will increment object name would be change..say tempItemi, tempItemi1, tempItemi2...then I have pass all these objects into `NSArray *items= = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:`...

Comment: There is no sense for doing this. After you add objects to array you can't know their names.

Comment: no man...every time when object changes(tempItemi) ..my values will be change of yValue and Width..bcz populating from the plist

Comment: and then object with different names I have to pass in Nsarray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you just make the array mutable and then add the object each time like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// a mutable array means you can add objects to it!

for (int i = 0; i< [Array count]; i++)
{
    id object = [Array objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;


        ECGraphItem *tempItemi = [[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str = [objDict objectForKey:@"title"];

        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];
        tempItemi.isPercentage=YES;
        tempItemi.yValue=f;
        tempItemi.width=30;

        [items addObject: tempItemi];
        //in array need to pass all the initialized values

       }
}

    [graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Anyways `items` in your original code will be reinitializing each time and you are drawing a new histogram each time so your code won't work... This should work...

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is ok but,
`NSArray *items` will always contain only one item at each loop.
just declare that outside for loop as `NSMutableArray`,
 and go with the same code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to make variable dynamically as

ECGraphItem *tempItemi = [[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

here `i` will be changing in the loop,

You can create a `NSDictionary` with key/value as per with your tempItem1/2/3/4.... as key and  save values by alloc/init.

Then instead of a variable `tempItem32`, you will be using `[dict valueForKey:@"tempItem32"]`.

EDIT:

Check this example if this may come handy

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string%d",i];
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i*i] forKey:string];

}
NSLog(@"dict is %@",dict);

NSString *fetch=@"string5";
NSLog(@"val:%@, for:%@",[dict valueForKey:fetch],fetch);
```