# Make variable names variables (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to do something like this:

.h

```
LocalRoom* zone1;
LocalRoom* zone2;
LocalRoom* zone3;
LocalRoom* zone4;
etc....
```

.m

```
NSString *number = 1;
NSString *variable = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"zone%@", number]
[[variable variableValue] broadcastChatMessage:redStringPrefix fromUser:@"server"];
```

emulating:

```
[zone1 broadcastChatMessage:redStringPrefix fromUser:@"server"];
```

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use an `NSMutableDictionary` if you need named values?

Comment: Or you can use obj-c/runtime....

Comment: Creating variables at runtime.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Not sure what you mean. That's possible with `malloc()` too...

Comment: You could do what @AnoopVaidya is suggesting, but it isn't really practical or readable compared to just using a mutable dictionary.  Associated objects would work, for example.

Comment: that is why my first reply was dict and second one obj-c runtime :)

Comment: i wonder is this can be an hint ?  NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string%d",i];
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i*i] forKey:string];

}
NSLog(@"dict is %@",dict);

NSString *fetch=@"string5";
NSLog(@"val:%@, for:%@",[dict valueForKey:fetch],fetch);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028547/initialize-multiple-objects-with-different-name/14028705#14028705

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @property(strong) NSMutableDictionary *zones;

 -(id)init {
   ....
   _zones = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   ....
 }

 aZone = [_zones objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zone%d", someZoneNumber]];
```

... etc ...

Answer (score 6):

Given names like “zone1”, “zone2”, etc., I would make an array rather than a dictionary. Either way, these should not be separate variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar using [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).  You would write

```
[[self valueForKey:variable] broadcastChatMessage:redStringPrefix fromUser:@"server"];
```

rather than

```
[[variable variableValue] broadcastChatMessage:redStringPrefix fromUser:@"server"];
```

This would of course require that `zone1`, `zone2`, etc. are instance variables (or properties) on `self`.

Comment: This'll work, but I'd suggest against KVC vs. just using an NSMutableDictionary.